# Manejador de eventos javascript

Tags: javascript, eventos, poo

Estoy queriendo usar eventos personalizados por `Javascript`, y la verdad que intente encontrar algo pero o no encuentro la información indicada o no la comprendo, por lo cual se me ocurrió hacer mi `eventManager`, bastante rustico la verdad pero es lo que puede hacer por el momento para no seguir frenado, el único problema que tengo es que no se como ejecutar mi *handler* dentro del objeto `EventManager`.

Aquí dejo el código a ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

Mi problema esta en esta linea, claramente esta mal pero no se como hacerlo
`this._events[i].handler (this._events[i].args)`.

```
var EventCustom=function() {
    this.eventName;
    this.handler;
    this.args;
};



var EventManager=function(siteController) {
    this.siteController=siteController;
    // es un array de objetos de tipo EventCustom
    this._events = [];
};

EventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN = 'EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN';


EventManager.prototype.addEventListener = function (evnt, handler,args)
{
    var tmpEvent = new EventCustom();
    tmpEvent.eventName = evnt;
    tmpEvent.handler = handler;
    tmpEvent.args = args;

    this._events.push(tmpEvent);

    //alert("addEventListener:"+this._events[0].eventName);
    //handler
} 

EventManager.prototype.dispatchEvent = function (evnt, args)
{


    for(var i=0; i< this._events.length; i++)
    {
        if(this._events[i].eventName == evnt)
        {
            **// aca deberia ejecutar el handler pero no me funciona
            //this._events[i].handler (this._events[i].args)//**
        }
    }

} 


var pruebaFn = function()
{
    alert("prueba");
}



var eventManager = new EventManager(this);
eventManager.addEventListener(EventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN,pruebaFn);
eventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN);
```

Si ademas me quieren recomendar una mejor forma de hacerlo, buenísimo. La verdad es que estoy armando todo un sistema en `Javascript` y quiero pasar ciertas llamadas a eventos ya que es mucho mas ordenado.

Comment: ¿Por que sería necesario usar `EventCustom`? ¿Un simple [`Pub/Sub`](https://davidwalsh.name/pubsub-javascript) no te serviría?

Comment: Sugiero el uso del siguiente API https://github.com/Olical/EventEmitter/wiki

Comment: Para hacer eventos personalizados, no es más práctico usar [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent)? Que es JavaScript puro y duro y no necesitas generarte un prototipo sólo para esto?

Answer (score 3):

Sugiero el uso del siguiente API  https://github.com/Olical/EventEmitter/wiki

En este api muestra como se pueden implementar eventos a nivel de javascript como se maneja en Node JS, es tan simple como:

```
//Generador de eventos
var event = new EventEmitter();
event.emit("nombreDeEvento", data);

//Cliente de eventos
event.on('nombreDeEvento', function(data){

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Creo que el problema es que no le estas pasando ningún argumento..
Te he reescrito un poco el código y creo que hace los que estás buscando:

```js
var EventCustom = function(evnt, handler, args) {
  this.eventName = evnt;
  this.handler = handler;
  this.args = args;
};

var EventManager = function(scope) {
  var that = scope;
  this._events = [];
};
EventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN_1 = 'EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN_1';
EventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN_2 = 'EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN_2';

EventManager.prototype.addEventListener = function(evnt, handler, args) {
  this._events.push(new EventCustom(evnt, handler, args));
}
EventManager.prototype.dispatchEvent = function(evnt, args) {
  for (event in this._events) {
    if (this._events[event].eventName === evnt) {
      this._events[event].handler(this._events[event].args);
    }
  }
}

var pruebaFn1 = function(args) {
  alert("pruebaFn " + args);
}
var pruebaFn2 = function(args) {
  alert("pruebaFn2 " + args);
}

var eventManager = new EventManager();
eventManager.addEventListener(EventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN_1, pruebaFn1, "ok1");
eventManager.addEventListener(EventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN_2, pruebaFn2, "ok2");
eventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN_1);
```

** Actualizo la respuesta con un código más óptimo ;)

```js
var EventManager = function() {
  this._events = {};
};
EventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN_1 = 'EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN_1';
EventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN_2 = 'EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN_2';

EventManager.prototype.addEventListener = function(id, h, a) {
  var e = {handler: h,args: a};
  this._events[id] = (!this._events[id]) ? [] : this._events[id];
  this._events[id].push(e);
}
EventManager.prototype.dispatchEvent = function(id) {
  for (e in this._events[id]) {
      this._events[id][e].handler(this._events[id][e].args);
  }
}

var pruebaFn1 = function(args) {
  alert("pruebaFn1 " + args);
}
var pruebaFn2 = function(args) {
  alert("pruebaFn2 " + args);
}

var eventManager = new EventManager();
eventManager.addEventListener(EventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN_1, pruebaFn1, "ok1a");
eventManager.addEventListener(EventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN_1, pruebaFn1, "ok1b");
eventManager.addEventListener(EventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN_2, pruebaFn2, "ok2");
eventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN_1);
```

Comment: Tu respuesta tiene varios detalles, por ejemplo: 1. ¿Cual sería el objetivo de crear un `EventCustom` en lugar de un objeto común y corriente? (En si no estas usando para nada el `event` creado). 2. En el método `addEventListener`, ¿para que serviría pasar `args`? (Realmente no le estas dando ningún uso). 3. En el método `dispatchEvent`, es poco óptimo ya que se recorre completamente el arreglo `_events` para ejecutar **solo aquellos** con el `eventName` indicado.

Comment: Más que nada era por seguir el código que Pablo utilizaba.

Comment: Actualizo la respuesta con un código más optimo ;)

Comment: ook editado otra vez, a ver que tal ;)

Comment: Muchos mejor. Un último detalle, que se me olvido comentar es que, comúnmente los `args`, se pasan al emitir el evento, ya que es en ese punto donde se sabe que se quiere comunicar a todos los que escuchan/aguardan el evento.